# Win32 application still running in background after closing

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am a beginner programmer.

In this code I want to create a window of one color in Win32 API using the C language. I am using the Windows PowerShell and MinGW to compile it. It works, but whenever I try to compile it again after closing it I get this error: *…/mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file out.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status*

As far as I am concerned, this is a linkage problem and it occurs because Windows cannot make the linkage with the program already being in execution. I do not wish to kill the execution all the time in the Task Manager.

I don't think the code is beyond what Microsoft's documentation tells me to do, I have simply wrapped it in functions and structs instead of writing everything in WinMain, the application loop can be found there. I am creating an RGB array in WM_CREATE and passing it to HBITMAP in WM_PAINT in case you are wondering what I have done, that's why the repeated height and width which I pretend to change later. Here is the code:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Window Procedure
HBITMAP bitmap_handle;
COLORREF *rgb_p=NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK window_procedure_func(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            int width=500;
            int height=500;
            rgb_p=(COLORREF*)malloc(width*height*sizeof(COLORREF));
            int  pixel_count=0;
            for(int row=0; row<height; row++)
            {
                for(int col=0; col<width; col++)
                {
                    rgb_p[pixel_count]=RGB(255, 0, 0);
                    pixel_count++;
                }
            }
        }
        break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            int width=500;
            int height=500;
            HBITMAP bitmap_handle=CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 32, rgb_p);
      
            PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
            HDC             hdc;
            BITMAP          bitmap;
            HDC             hdcMem;
            HGDIOBJ         oldBitmap;

            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, bitmap_handle);

            GetObject(bitmap_handle, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
            DeleteDC(hdcMem);

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        }
        break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            free(rgb_p);
            DeleteObject(bitmap_handle);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Simple functions to initalize a window
struct window_wrapper
{
    WNDCLASS window_class;
    HWND window_handle;
};

WNDCLASS window_class_ini(char *window_name, HINSTANCE instance_handle, WNDPROC window_procedure)
{
    WNDCLASS window_class={};
    window_class.lpfnWndProc=window_procedure;
    window_class.hInstance=instance_handle;
    window_class.lpszClassName=window_name;
    return window_class;
}

HWND window_handle_ini(char *window_name, HINSTANCE instance_handle, int width, int height)
{
    return CreateWindow(
        window_name,
        window_name,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        250, 250, width, height,
        NULL,  
        NULL,
        instance_handle,
        NULL);
}

struct window_wrapper *malloc_window_wrapper(char *window_name, HINSTANCE instance_handle, WNDPROC window_procedure, int windows_status, int width, int height)
{
    struct window_wrapper *window_wrapper_p=NULL;
    window_wrapper_p=(struct window_wrapper*)malloc(sizeof(struct window_wrapper));
    window_wrapper_p->window_class=window_class_ini(window_name, instance_handle, window_procedure);
    RegisterClass(&window_wrapper_p->window_class);
    window_wrapper_p->window_handle=window_handle_ini(window_name, instance_handle, width, height);
    ShowWindow(window_wrapper_p->window_handle, windows_status);
    return window_wrapper_p;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Windows Entry Point
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    LRESULT CALLBACK (*procedure_p)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)=&window_procedure_func;
    struct window_wrapper *wrapper=malloc_window_wrapper("window_name", hInstance, (WNDPROC)procedure_p, nCmdShow, 500, 500);
    MSG msg={};
    int running=1;
    while(running)
    {
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if(msg.message==WM_QUIT)
        {
            running=0;
        }
    }

    free(wrapper);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to use exit() also instead of return 0 at the end but no success. I appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your message loop is structured incorrectly. Your `if` statement is reached only when `PeekMessage()` returns false, meaning the contents of `msg` are *indeterminate*. So the `if` will never see a valid `WM_QUIT` message (or *any* valid message, for that matter) to break the loop.

Get rid of the `running` variable, and use this loop instead:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDPROC procedure_p = &window_procedure_func;
    struct window_wrapper *wrapper = malloc_window_wrapper("window_name", hInstance, procedure_p, nCmdShow, 500, 500);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    free(wrapper);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If [`GetMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) always returns `-1` (which means error), then your code will get stuck in an infinite loop. Note that the return type `BOOL` is misleading in this case, as the function can return `-1` (which means error), `0` (which means `WM_QUIT`) or something else (which means not `WM_QUIT`). The linked official Microsoft documentation for the function explicitly states that you should not use `while (GetMessage( lpMsg, hWnd, 0, 0))`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel the loop I presented is perfectly fine, and will never get stuck in an infinite loop. See [When will GetMessage return -1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873): "*the function fails **if hWnd is an invalid window handle or lpMsg is an invalid pointer** ... If your parameters are exactly a valid pointer to a valid MSG structure, a null window handle, no starting message range filter, no ending message range filter, then **Get­Message will not fail with -1**.*"

Comment: @Andreas It does indeed explicitly state that you should not use `while (GetMessage( lpMsg, hWnd, 0, 0))`. And the code in this answer does not. It passes 0 for the window handle.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel  I thank for the answers but that is not what I had in mind, but it had showed me on what to do. I intended to create an update and draw function for my application so that's why the nested loop. In this case what apparently works is by putting the last condition inside the PeekMessage loop so the program always checks whether WM_QUIT is called, then set running to 0 as I have done. If its put outside, then it is not always the case as you have said. I've got no problems so far with this approach.

Comment: @LucianoMachado the correct solution is to use the proper loop to begin with. You are not. At best, checking for `WM_QUIT` on every message that `PeekMessage()` returns true for is less efficient than simply letting `GetMessage()` return 0 when `WM_QUIT` is received. `bool running = true; while (running) { while (PeekMessage(&msg, ...)) { ... if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) running = false; } }` is not better than `while (GetMessage(&msg, ...)) { ... }`